# How to resize the thumb image in a seekBar?

Tags: android, seekbar

I can get the thumb to change to different images in mipmap when the progress changes, but I can't change their size.
If I just change the size of the image files, then the bar won't show.
I'm sure some of these lines are unnecessary, but I have no idea which:

Java (in OnFinishInflate):

```
LevelListDrawable likey_bar_draw;
        likey_bar_draw = (LevelListDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.likey_bar_hearts);
        likey_bar_draw.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50));
        likey_bar_draw.setLevel(5);
        likeyBar.setThumb(likey_bar_draw);

        likeyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                LevelListDrawable likey_bar_draw;
                likey_bar_draw = (LevelListDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.likey_bar_hearts);
                Integer progressInt = progress; //for some reason it won't let me convert progress to a string
                Log.d(TAG, "likey level: " + progressInt.toString()); //even though it's allegedly an integer...
                likey_bar_draw.setLevel(progress);
                seekBar.setThumb(likey_bar_draw);
            }
```

layout:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/likey_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="5"
        android:thumb="@drawable/likey_bar_hearts"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/likey_bar_progress"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:maxHeight="50dp" />
```

likey_bar_hearts xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:minLevel="0" android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@mipmap/heart_gray_100">
        <shape>
            <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
...(more items similar to this)
```

Help??

Comment: why you use mipmap folder for regular drawables? It's not for this. See: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

Comment: I thought it was. Is that why it won't let me resize the thumb?